# Como desativar o método on Stop?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e estou usando 3 fragments em um slider layout. E quando eu deslizo da primeira aba para a terceira aba, a minha primeira aba chama o método onStop e consequentemente, tudo o que está nesse fragment é destruído.

Há alguma forma de interromper o método onStop?
Desejo que ele não seja chamado.

fragment:

```
/**
 * Created by Lucas on 01/10/2017.
 */

public class ProdutosFragment extends Fragment  {

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
Button Filtrar;
List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
int i=0;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Produtos>arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
SearchView searchView;
ProgressDialog progressDialogFiltrar;
int conta=0;
@Nullable
@Override



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.produtosfragment,container,false);


    String NomeSupermercado = Singleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getNomeSupermercado();
    FirebaseProdutos firebaseProdutos= new FirebaseProdutos();
    FirebaseAutenticarSupermercado FirebaseAutenticarSupermercado = new FirebaseAutenticarSupermercado();
    FirebaseAutenticarSupermercado.Autenticar();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Estabelecimentos/Estabelecimentos/Supermercados/"+NomeSupermercado+"/produtos/");
    Filtrar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btfiltrar);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    searchView=(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setSelected(false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Cerveja, Morango, Aymoré, Bebidas etc");
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    closeKeyboard();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
            // filter listview
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {



      newText= newText.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<Produtos> newList= new ArrayList<>();
                for(Produtos produtos: arrayList){
                    String name=produtos.getProduto().toLowerCase();
                    String marca=produtos.getMarca().toLowerCase();
//                    String caracteristica=produtos.getCaracteristica().toLowerCase();
                    String categoria=produtos.getCategoria().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText)||marca.contains(newText)||categoria.contains(newText)){
                        newList.add(produtos);
                    }
                }
                adapter.setFilter(newList);
                return true;
            }
        });


    if(adapter==null||arrayList==null||arrayList.size()<1||recyclerView==null){
        ProgressDialog prog= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//Assuming that you are using fragments.
        prog.setTitle("Aguarde");
        prog.setMessage("Carregando os produtos");
        prog.setCancelable(false);
        prog.setIndeterminate(true);
        prog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        prog.show();
    databaseReference.orderByChild("produto").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();
            adapter=null;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
            areas.add(" "+"Categoria");
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Produtos Listar= new Produtos();
                Listar = objSnapshot.getValue(Produtos.class);
                arrayList.add(Listar);
                areas.add(Listar.getCategoria());
            }
            adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            prog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    }


    Filtrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            searchView.setQuery("",false);
            closeKeyboard();
            //Cria a view a ser utilizada no dialog
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtro, null);

            //Obtém uma referencia ao hinner
            final Spinner SpinnerCategoria = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnercategoria);
            //final Spinner SpinnerEspecificos = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerprodutosespecificos);

            Button Limpar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btlimparfiltro);
            Button Filtro = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btfiltrarproduto);

            builder.setView(view);

            final AlertDialog builderx=builder.show();
            Filtro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Categoria = SpinnerCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.d("Categoria","Categoria Escolhida"+Categoria);
                    if(Categoria.equals(" "+"Categoria")){
                        builderx.dismiss();
                    }
                    else {
                        ProgressDialog proga= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//Assuming that you are using fragments.
                        proga.setTitle("Aguarde");
                        proga.setMessage("Estamos filtrando os produtos para você :)");
                        proga.setCancelable(false);
                        proga.setIndeterminate(true);
                        proga.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        proga.show();
                        databaseReference.orderByChild("categoria").equalTo(Categoria).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                arrayList.clear();
                                adapter=null;
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);

                                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Produtos Listar;
                                    Listar = objSnapshot.getValue(Produtos.class);
                                    arrayList.add(Listar);
                                    i++;
                                    Log.d("Quantidade de produtos", "Quantidade de produtos"+i);
                                }
                                adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                proga.dismiss();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        builderx.dismiss();
                    }


                }
            });
            Limpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Limpar();
                }
            });
            HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
            hashSet.addAll(areas);
            areas.clear();
            areas.addAll(hashSet);
            //Alphabetic sorting.
            Collections.sort(areas);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> categoriaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
            categoriaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            SpinnerCategoria.setAdapter(categoriaAdapter);

                        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onResume() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onPause() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onSavedInstanceState() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onStop() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onDestroy() chamado");
}

private void closeKeyboard() {
    View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if(view!= null){
        InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }

}

private void Limpar() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndexActivity.class);

    startActivity(i);
}


}
```

Comment: Poste seu código, irá ajudar a dar uma resposta

Comment: prontinho, código postado do meu fragment.

Comment: O problema encontrado, é que infelizmente o método onStop ele é chamado, e eu não quero que o fragment realize este método.

Comment: exatamente em que o onstop te atrapalha?

Comment: eu tenho um recyclerview que carrega milhares de produtos. Portanto, ele demora um pouco a listar. Quando o onStop é chamado e consequentemente o meu fragment todo se torna nulo, quando eu vou para a tela do fragment novamente, todos os dados precisam ser carregados.
esse é o problema :/

Comment: Se vc carrega os dados no onCreateView, ao chamar o onStop ele n vai recarregar os itens ao voltar para o fragment

Comment: O que vc está fazendo é abrir o fragment novamente, e não chamar o onResume, o onStop só pausa, ele n vai destruir seus dados

Comment: Outro coisa, seu fragment é carregado em tabs? Se for, ele realmente é destruído ao passar por +2 fragments, o que vc deve fazer é fazer seu ViewPager aumentar o limit de itens antes de destruir as Views, pra isso basta fazer: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(quantidade);`

Comment: Wow! Era exatamente o que eu queria, Woton! Muito obrigado!